Why does pandas .reindex() not keep data with equivalent sized index?
Lets say we have this dummy data :
dates=pd.date_range("2020-02-01","2021-02-01",freq="MS")
features=["foo","bar"]
cols=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([features,dates],names=["features","dates"])
projects=["p1","p2","p3"]`

df=pd.DataFrame(index=projects,columns=cols,data=np.random.randn(3,26))`


And I create this new index that tries to flatten the column levels :
level_0=list(map(lambda t:t[0],df.columns.to_numpy()))
level_1=list(map(lambda t:t[1],df.columns.to_numpy()))
ind=[i+"_"+j.strftime("%Y_%m") for i,j in zip(level_0,level_1)]


The length of my index is the same as my number of columns. So why is it that when i reindex, I get NaN. The index is equivalent to the previous should it not save all of the data and make life easier ?
(
 df
 .reindex(columns=ind)
)


enter image description here
I was expecting to keep the same values. Since the indices are equivalent, no data should be lost.

pandas.DataFrame.reindex will conform the dataframe values to the new index.
See this as an example:
df = pd.DataFrame({"a": [1, 2, 3], "b": [4, 5, 6]})

   a  b
0  1  4
1  2  5
2  3  6

df = df.reindex(columns=["b", "a"])

   b  a
0  4  1
1  5  2
2  6  3

You can also add or remove indices. If you reindex the columns with a new column that didn't exist before, a new one will be created. Similarly, existing column that aren't in the reindex will be dropped.
df = df.reindex(columns=["a", "c"])

   a   c
0  1 NaN
1  2 NaN
2  3 NaN


What you probably want instead is to set new columns:
df.columns = ind

    foo_2020_02  foo_2020_03  foo_2020_04  foo_2020_05  foo_2020_06  ...  bar_2020_10  bar_2020_11  bar_2020_12  bar_2021_01  bar_2021_02
p1     1.470715    -1.948202     0.263808    -0.840240    -1.730577  ...     2.267247    -0.032631     0.256322     1.544889    -0.241991
p2    -0.332706     2.509333     1.280835    -0.261680     0.048782  ...     1.021974     0.058752    -0.620607    -0.463741    -0.764401
p3     0.873049     0.361361     1.211950    -0.282604    -0.474361  ...    -0.107638    -0.630635    -0.659733    -0.877354     0.856980


Accroding to documentation this is expected outcome.

DataFrame.reindex Conform DataFrame to new index with optional filling logic.Places NA/NaN in locations having no value in the previous index

Try following code on your machine
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': range(1,10), 'B':range(2,11)}})
df.reindex(columns = ['A', 'B', 'C'])
df.reindex(columns = ['A', 'C'])
df.reindex(columns = ['C', 'B'])

this command do not rename the columns of dataframe but make a new index. Old values under old index are kept, new are filled with NaN or any other value you put to fillna.
to rename in you code example use:
df.columns = ind

